# Linux client that can communicate with NetMeeting

Tags: video, chat

Are there any NetMeeting compatible softwares for Linux environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ekiga [claims](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Ekiga_Interoperability) to be interoperable with NetMeeting. It is available at http://www.ekiga.org/.

Comment: ty4the link, but it gives a blank page :O - I will try it later

Comment: I guess their Wiki is down for some reason. Either way, it claimed to be able to communicate with NetMeeting when I read it ;)